Why is my scss module file is removed after hmr in remix application after changing tsx file?
I'm new to remix and I'm trying to get css modules working, it looks like the css is removed from the html after a hot reload
I seem to have a pretty basic setup for my application and at the initial load the CSS is being applied but for some reason when I edit my component the text turns back to black, what is happening?
package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@remix-run/node": "^2.9.2",
    "@remix-run/react": "^2.9.2",
    "@remix-run/serve": "^2.9.2",
    "isbot": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@remix-run/dev": "^2.9.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.4",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "sass": "^1.77.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "^5.1.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=20.0.0"
  }
}

_index.tsx
import classes from "../styles/global.module.scss";

export default function Index() {
  return <h1 className={classes["test"]}>Welcome to Remix</h1>;
}


global.module.scss
.test {
  color: #d90000;
}

root.tsx
import type { LinksFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import {
  Links,
  Meta,
  Outlet,
  Scripts,
  ScrollRestoration,
} from "@remix-run/react";

import globalStyles from "~/styles/global.module.scss?url";

export function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        {children}
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return <Outlet />;
}

vite.config.json
import { vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    remix({
      future: {
        v3_fetcherPersist: true,
        v3_relativeSplatPath: true,
        v3_throwAbortReason: true,
      },
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
  ],
});



I guess we'll never know...

I guess we'll never know...

I have the same issue. Did you figure it out?

Nope, I guess we'll never know...

I'm going to attempt to do a minimal reproduction and see if someone on their repo can help.

I already asked the remix guys, but they aren't sure why it happens. Here's my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/sad-turing-4vlsm7

Got a link to that? Thanks.

Link to the conversation? It was in their discord

Ah, OK. I think I will try on their repo and see if that makes any progress. I'll let you know the outcome.

The issue is with styling being added directly to elements in the routes causing HMR to crash. Full explanation and example here https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/10011.
